# Magento error in Checkout when using saved addresses

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.6

I'm using **Magento2.2.6**.

When trying to **checkout as a guest** and filling manually the **shipping address**, everything works fine.
When trying to `checkout` as logged user it gives and error like this:
[image: error]

When I try to checkout **as logged user** but filling in manually a `new address`, it also works fine.

It is only throwing the error when it takes the saved addresses from my profile.

I use a custom `courier module` for `shipping cost estimation`.

Here is a link to the file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-6wyyjXN-Cp16wuVTY7TSUZ1v80b5v25

Can somebody help?

The error is from here:

> $judet_dest = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", 
>   $detalii_dest["region"]);

Where:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
$shippingAddress = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
$detalii_dest = $shippingAddress->getData();
```

Comment: Error occurs when the customer has two or more address

Comment: because the `$detalii_dest["region"]` returns an array on that case

Comment: so the best solution would be to use reset() or current() array function, in that case it will get only the value of the first or current array

Comment: I added:$judet_dest = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT",  next($detalii_dest["region"]));  in line 290. It works fine for the existing saved addressed

Comment: But when I add a new address in the checkout, I have a new error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wrd8MyphBzKvMBTeJ-jg5mPkPQwCtcKZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: yeah that's right, because every new address added on checkout are automatically save in the addressbook of the customer

Comment: next() will print the second array item like if you have array city = array(city1, city2); next will print city2

Comment: using session  at shipping calculation, it not good idea

Comment: I used an if to check on which scenario is

Comment: if (is_array($detalii_dest["region"])){
     $judet_dest = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT",  next($detalii_dest["region"]));
    }else{
     $judet_dest = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT",  $detalii_dest["region"]);
    }

Comment: now it is working ok

Answer (score 1):

Error occurs when the current logged in customer has two or more addresses. Because what happens is, your code tries to load all the region or city that was registered or associated with the user.

Try this, replace your iconv lines with these:

```
$city = current($detalii_dest["city"]);
$region= current($detalii_dest["region"]);
$localitate_dest = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $city);
$judet_dest = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT",  $region);
```